# Limit-related inequalities with absolute values

Tags: limits, inequality, absolute-value

Recently I decided to learn calculus on my own and I stumbled across something which I cannot figure why is correct.

Let $f$ be some function for which you know only that if $0<|x-3|<1$, then $|f(x)-5|<0.1$

It is necessary true then that

If $|x-2.5|<0.3$, then $|f(x)-5|<0.1$

I can't for the life of me figure out why that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|x-2.5|<0.3$ then $2.2<x<2.8$. Therefore, $2<x<4$, or $|x-3|<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|x-2.5|<0.3$ is equivalent to $2.2<x<2.8$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
|x - 2.5| < 0.3 & \implies
-0.3 < x - 2.5 < 0.3 \\
& \implies -0.8 < x - 3 < -0.2 \\
& \implies |x - 3| < 0.8 \\
& \implies |x - 3| < 1.
\end{align}